# How do I enable MySQL binary logging?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-event

I tried to use [simple example of](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events#quick-start)  [mysql-events package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events) but when i tried to use it , i got this error:

> Error: ER_NO_BINARY_LOGGING: You are not using binary logging

so i changed my.cnf:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

#what i added:
log_bin = "/home/erfan/salone-entezar/server/"


!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

but when i tried to restart mysql (using `$ sudo service mysql restart`) this error has happened:

> Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
>   See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

and this is `systemctl status mysql.service` :

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-11-18 20:16:48 IRST; 3s ago
  Process: 8838 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 8831 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8838 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE); Control PID: 8839 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─8839 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─8850 sleep 1

Nov 18 20:16:48 erfan-m systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Nov 18 20:16:48 erfan-m mysql-systemd-start[8831]: my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 19!
Nov 18 20:16:48 erfan-m mysql-systemd-start[8831]: my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Nov 18 20:16:48 erfan-m systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

What should i do now and what is my problem?

Comment: `Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 19!` should help. It means: it belongs below `[mysqld]`.

Comment: thanks! @Solarflare

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## for UBUNTU

i have to add `socketPath : '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`  to `dsn` variable in code and also correcting `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` as below :

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[mysqld] #grouping  config options is important
# Must be unique integer from 1-2^32
server-id        = 1
# Row format required for ZongJi
binlog_format    = row
# Directory must exist. This path works for Linux. Other OS may require
#   different path.
log_bin          = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

and at last restart it with `$sudo service mysql restart`

## for CentOS

i have to add `socketPath : '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'` to `dsn` variable in code and also correcting `/etc/my.cnf` as below :

```
[mysqld]
# Must be unique integer from 1-2^32
server-id        = 1
# Row format required for ZongJi
binlog_format    = row
# Directory must exist. This path works for Linux. Other OS may require
#   different path.
log_bin          = /var/log/mariadb/mariadb-bin.log

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

and at last restart it with `$systemctl restart mariadb`

**NOTE** : CentOS 7 has replaced MySQL with [MariaDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB). So there is deference between `log_bin` path of UBUNTU and CentOS .